# Control number of active actors of a type

Tags: akka, akka.net

Is it possible to control the number of active actors in play? In a nutshell, I have an actor called `AuthoriseVisaPaymentActor` which handles the message `VisaPaymentMessage`. I have a parallel loop which sends 10 messages but I am trying to create something which allows for 3 actors to be working simultaneously and the other 7 messages will be blocked and waiting for an actor to be available. Is this possible? I am currently using a `RoundRobin` setup which I believe I have misunderstood..

```
            var actor = sys.ActorOf(
                Props.Create<AuthoriseVisaPaymentActor>().WithRouter(new RoundRobinPool(1)));

            actor.Tell(new VisaPaymentMessage(curr.ToString(), 9.99M, "4444"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To set up a round robin pools/groups, you need to specify the actor paths to use.  This can either be done statically in your [hocon settings](https://getakka.net/articles/actors/routers.html#roundrobin) or dynamically in code (see below).  As far as messages being blocked, Akka's mailboxes already do that for you; it won't process any new messages until the one it is currently processing has been handled.  It just holds them in queue until the actor is ready to handle it.

```
// Setup the three actors
var actor1 = sys.ActorOf(Props.Create<AuthoriseVisaPaymentActor>());
var actor2 = sys.ActorOf(Props.Create<AuthoriseVisaPaymentActor>());
var actor3 = sys.ActorOf(Props.Create<AuthoriseVisaPaymentActor>());

// Get their paths
var routees = new[] { actor1.Path.ToString(), actor2.Path.ToString(), actor3.Path.ToString() };

// Create a new actor with a router
var router = sys.ActorOf(Props.Empty.WithRouter(new RoundRobinGroup(routees)));

router.Tell(new VisaPaymentMessage(curr.ToString(), 9.99M, "4444"));
```